# How to find the size of a text file without using ftell, and other non-standard functions?

Tags: c, file, struct, txt

First of all, I'm in completely standard C.
Let's say we have

```
typedef struct student{
    int grade[3];
    char name[10];
} student;
```

some amount of these structures in a .txt document.

I need to bring them into an array of structures, where I can manipulate them and put them back into the file. The only part I am struggling with is taking the structures out of the file, as we do not know how many structures there are.

Using ftells is only applicable for small-scale binary files (as far as I understand).
The only libraries I am working with are stdio.h, stdlib.h, and string.h

```
int findSize(){
    FILE* fp = fopen("aaa.txt", "r");
    int size = 0;
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while(fp != NULL){
        student temp;
        fscanf(fp, "%s%d%d%d",  temp.name, temp.grade + 0, temp.grade + 1, temp.grade + 2);
        printf("Name: %s\nGrades: %d %d %d\n", temp.name, temp.grade[0], temp.grade[1], temp.grade[2]);
        size++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return size;
}
student* readFile(int size){
    FILE* fp = fopen("aaa.txt", "r");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    printf("Size of file:\n%d", size);
    student* stArray = allocMem(size);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        student temp;
        fscanf(fp, "%s%d%d%d",  temp.name, temp.grade + 0, temp.grade + 1, temp.grade + 2);
        stArray[i] = temp;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return stArray;
}
```

we input the size we find in findSize into readFile.
In the main function, we say

```
int size = 0;
student* st = allocMem(findSize());
st = readFile(&size);
printStudents(st, size);
```

is there any way to do this?

Comment: Read the file to the end, count the bytes.

Comment: What is your basis for this "understanding" about `ftell`?

Comment: @ScottHunter From the C standard: "*The ftell function obtains the current value of the file position indicator for the stream pointed to by stream. For a binary stream, the value is the number of characters from the beginning of the file. For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified information, usable by the fseek function for returning the file position indicator for the stream to its position at the time of the ftell call; the difference between two such return values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of characters written or read.*"

Comment: `ftell()` is defined in the C standard..

Comment: You could realloc the array if it's full or use a linked list instead of an array.

Comment: Read the file with variable-length data twice. The first time, count but don't store. Or, make the first line state the number of records in the file.

Comment: Aside: `while(fp != NULL)`, with nothing in the loop that changes the value of `fp`, will either iterate zero times, or iterate infinitely. Try using the return of `fscanf` to control a loop like such as this (e.g., `while (3 == fscanf(file, "%e%f%g", ...`). `fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);` and `fclose(fp);` invoke [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) if `fp` is `NULL`. Even if it is just a throw-away example, try to write correct code as it is easier for those helping to make amendments to ([Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).